# Get a value from a certain key

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

In NodeJS,JavaScript, I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
console.log(object1.Tags)

[
  { Key: 'branch', Value: 'master' },
  { Key: 'env', Value: 'staging' },
  { Key: 'Name', Value: 'host-number-137' },
  {
    Key: 'DNSalt',
    Value: 'name.of.dns'
  },
  { Key: 'env_role', Value: 'dev' },
  { Key: 'role', Value: 'app' },
  { Key: 'userId', Value: 'U123456789' }
]
```

I'm trying to get the value of the key that holds `DNSalt` but I can't seem to do it.

In NodeJS/JavaScript, is it possible to get the value of the key called "DNSalt" (AKA `name.of.dns`)?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: You can iterate through the array and search for the object containing the correct `key`. Once you find it, then you can read the value.

Comment: [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 1):

An idea can be to use `array.find` that take a condition and return first element that match the condition

```js
var data = [
  { Key: 'branch', Value: 'master' },
  { Key: 'env', Value: 'staging' },
  { Key: 'Name', Value: 'host-number-137' },
  {
    Key: 'DNSalt',
    Value: 'name.of.dns'
  },
  { Key: 'env_role', Value: 'dev' },
  { Key: 'role', Value: 'app' },
  { Key: 'userId', Value: 'U123456789' }
];

const res = data.find(obj => obj.Key === 'DNSalt');
console.log(res.Value);
```